# Cannot create app key in Azure Function App or Azure Function: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I created an Azure function app with an ARM template. The function app has a system-assigned identity. The identity has an access policy with get/list rights for keys, secrets, and certificates in the key vault. I also tried it with create/update rights additionally. But it did not solve the issue.

When I try to create a function key, I get the following error message in the web portal:
`Creating host key Failed to create <key name>: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.`

This is the template of the function (from export template):

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "function_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "test-fct-app",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "app_service_plan_id": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<app-service-plan-name>",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vnet_id": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<subnet-name>",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('function_app_name')]",
            "location": "Germany West Central",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('function_app_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('function_app_name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[parameters('app_service_plan_id')]",
                "reserved": false,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "siteConfig": {},
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "containerSize": 1536,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "httpsOnly": false,
                "redundancyMode": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('function_app_name'), '/web')]",
            "location": "Germany West Central",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('function_app_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                "phpVersion": "5.6",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "[concat('$', parameters('function_app_name'))]",
                "azureStorageAccounts": {},
                "scmType": "LocalGit",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": false,
                "javaVersion": "1.8",
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "vnetName": "8059ef61-4a93-4b13-bba1-e2a782a07360_function-subnet",
                "cors": {
                    "allowedOrigins": [
                        "https://functions.azure.com",
                        "https://functions-staging.azure.com",
                        "https://functions-next.azure.com"
                    ],
                    "supportCredentials": false
                },
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "managedServiceIdentityId": 2290,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
                "http20Enabled": false,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
                "reservedInstanceCount": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('function_app_name'), '/', parameters('function_app_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "location": "Germany West Central",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('function_app_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteName": "[parameters('function_app_name')]",
                "hostNameType": "Verified"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('function_app_name'), '/8059ef61-4a93-4b13-bba1-e2a782a07360_function-subnet')]",
            "location": "Germany West Central",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('function_app_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "vnetResourceId": "[concat(parameters('vnet_id'), '/subnets/function-subnet')]",
                "isSwift": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function fails at startup, nothing will show up in the Azure Portal properly. You will not be able to perform any action on this Azure Function.

Try to run this function in your emulator to see if you hit any errors.